# How to calculate damage made by falling objects

Tags: pathfinder-1e

This is an example. I use [Telekinetic Sphere](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinetic-sphere) to lift up 5000 pounds of stone. I get the sphere over a dragon and release the sphere. Now I have the problem of how to calculate the damage. I checked the Corebook but count not find anything. Anyone who can help me here?

Comment: I like the idea of having things fall to deal damage. I might have to look further into this for myself. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oddly enough it would require a ranged touch attack and grants a DC 15 reflex save for half damage, if they are aware. If the item is part of a trap then instead use trap rules.

The rules are under [environmental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules#TOC-Falling-Objects).

5000 pounds is about the weight of a huge creature so it would do 6d6, or 12d6 if it falls from over 150 feet. Where did I get 5000 is a huge creature? From the [space, reach, and threatened area](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) chart.

Comment: Even if you linked to the rules it might be worth pointing out that such attacks have a 20ft range increment. So from over 150ft (for the higher damage) that means you're in the 8th range increment with a -14 to your attack roll. That might make hitting even an unaware dragon not as automatic as it seems at first.

Comment: This is falling damage as in dropping it from a height, not a thrown attack where you have this range increment. But it does require an attack roll, hmm

Comment: If it's decided you need an attack roll, IIRC squares tend to have an AC of 5. For misses I'd typically use the Splash Weapon miss rules.